# Why doesn't SELECT INTO work for this stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
USE [VISION]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[!UPDATEGISDATA]    Script Date: 3/6/2024 11:20:34 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


    IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.!GISParcelData', N'U') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[!GISParcelData];    
    
    SELECT *INTO [dbo].[!GISParcelData]
    FROM [dbo].[!ViewGISParcelData]       

GO
```

I need a stored procedure (so that I can schedule it to run periodically) that will drop and re-create a table with the latest data from a view. I have the code shown above.

If I run THIS code alone as a separate query... it works:

```
SELECT * 
INTO [dbo].[!GISParcelData]
FROM [dbo].[!ViewGISParcelData]
```

It creates the table from the view (provided `!GISParcelData` table doesn't exist already; I delete it manually ahead of time to verify that it works).

However as part of the stored procedure... it claims "completed successfully", but if I manually delete the `!GISParcelData` table, it does not get re-created.

What am I doing wrong?

Do I need to copy the SQL from the view into my stored procedure?
This seems like it should be EASY, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I would ask why do you need to create an entire new table when you already have the data on `ViewGISParcelData` ?

Comment: *"if I manually delete the !GISParcelData table, it does not get re-created"* - How have you confirmed that the stored procedure is successfully executing on your periodic schedule.  How have you scheduled it?  Does that execution produce an error?

Comment: You are saying: "If the table exists, drop it and then select data into the table that i just dropped"

Comment: Also, you could always use TRUNCATE TABLE

Comment: @JorgeCampos - The GIS department needs to connect to a table, not a view because ArcGIS cannot see data in views, only tables.

Comment: @javdromero - yes, because I need to re-create a fresh table every time.

Comment: @David, I haven't even gotten to that point yet (scheduling) because I need the procedure to work, first.

Comment: @TomkatDF2: Did you execute the stored procedure at all?  What result did that produce?

Comment: @David "commands completed successfully" (as in the screenshot I posted)
However, if I manually delete !GISParcelData table ahead of time, it does NOT get re-created.

Comment: @javdromero - SELECT INTO creates tables that don't already exist, yes?

Comment: @TomkatDF2: Indeed, the image in the question shows that you have successfully *altered* (defined) a stored procedure.  It sounds like you haven't actually tested it yet though.  That would probably be your next step.

Comment: @David, when I first run it as a CREATE procedure, it only creates the procedure with the embedded code, it never creates any tables.  I have refreshed "Tables" to verify this.

Comment: @TomkatDF2: That's because defining a stored procedure does not execute that stored procedure.  It defines it.  You've simply misunderstood the tools you're using.  Your next step in testing the stored procedure would be to execute it and observe its results.

Comment: Highlight the SP name `[!UPDATEGISDATA]` and click execute to test running the procedure (vs creating/altering it)

Comment: @David does that require creating another stored procedure that has exec !UPDATEGISDATA as a command?

Comment: @TomkatDF2: It doesn't *require* that, no.  But if that's how you want to execute it then you certainly can.  Note that the same pattern repeats, you'd also need to execute *that* stored procedure in order to execute it.

Comment: @AaronDietz - YES.  That re-created the table!  However what is the next step to automating the procedure, so that I don't have to manually execute it, every time?
Do I just schedule it using SQL Server Agent "Jobs" etc?

Comment: "The GIS department needs to connect to a table, not a view because ArcGIS cannot see data in views, only tables. " Just give their user access to this particular view. You are trying to solution a rather simple problem in a very convoluted and resource excessive way.

Comment: @TomkatDF2 Yes an agent job is a perfectly good way to do it.  You would just put `EXEC [!UPDATEGISDATA]` in the code box and setup the schedule that you'd like.

Comment: @JorgeCampos - ArcGIS can't see data in views, only tables.  It's not a matter of user of access, it's a matter of functionality.

Comment: @AaronDietz - I got everything working as intended, THANK YOU!

Comment: @AaronDietz - can I remove the ALTER PROCEDURE line?  Or should I leave everything, as is?

Comment: You clearly did not understand what I meant. I recommend you reading about database permissions. More specifically table/view permissions.

Comment: @JorgeCampos - but a view is not persistent data.  ArcGIS cannot "refresh" the view, so it needs to connect to a table with the same data.  It's ok that the data is only periodically updated, as I can control that interval.

Comment: You are lacking some good concepts about how a RDBMs works like you did up here regarding how a procedure works. ArcGIS (being an application or a db user) it ultimately connects to the database through a `database user` and reads the data from an object (in this particular case a table). For that to happen the user it uses has READ access to that table. The "refresh" operation you mentioned is nothing else than a select to that table. Hence, allowing whatever *db user* ArcGIS is using to have read permission to the view will solve the problem more elegantly.

Comment: Here, after a quick google search, go through this thread, you might be able to understand what I'm talking about: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/allow-user-to-access-a-view-but-not-the-tables-behind-the-view

Comment: @JorgeCampos - yea, I apologize.  I'm way more familiar with VBA, where you can execute code while looking at it, "step thru," etc.

Comment: @JorgeCampos - ArcGIS can connect to the database and see the view, but when the view is accessed, there is no data in it.  ArcGIS has no way to "select" or "refresh" , but it can access static tables.  (Please keep in mind, I'm going by what I'm being told by our GIS director)

Comment: Probably missing some specific permission but without actually looking at the user privileges structure of your database it would be hard to pinpoint exactly what. A quick test you can do is to simply run (if you have permission) `grant select on [dbo].[!ViewGISParcelData] to whatever_is_the_user_ArcGIS_is_using_to_connect` and then ask them to check.

Comment: @JorgeCampos - when I try the "grant select" statement up there, it returns...

Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find the user 'SA', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

SA of course is the username we use to login to the database.

My original issue it seems is a "permissions" issue, after all, as GIS cannot see the data in my newly created GISParcelData table, either.  They can only see the column headers/ fields... but no data.

Comment: @JorgeCampos - just a note... GIS CAN ACCESS tables that already exist in the database, just not any views or tables that I create.

Comment: @David - I apologize for my misunderstanding.  I'm more accustomed to the VBA world, where you can execute code from within the procedure.  There is no need to close the procedure, right click on it, "execute," etc.  I'm still adapting to the SQL server domain, because I don't use it every day.

Comment: Than you need to login with a more privileged user.

Comment: @JorgeCampos - you're not going to believe this... the issue was ARCGIS.  Using a newer "pro" version resolved the issue!  All tables and views can now be accessed.

Comment: You appear to be missing a space `SELECT *INTO`....